# Does clang support CUDA __global__ function recursion?

Tags: recursion, cuda, clang

nvcc has supported recursive `__global__` functions. What about clang? I failed to compile the following code (using `clang++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.cu --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75 -ldl -lrt -lcudart_static -pthread -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -std=c++14`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void cuda_hello(int i){
    printf("Hello World from GPU!\n");
        if (i < 3) {
                cuda_hello<<<1,1>>>(i+1);
        }
}

int main() {
    cuda_hello<<<1,1>>>(0); 
    return 0;
}
```

. The error I got is

```
helloWorld.cu:6:3: error: reference to __global__ function 'cuda_hello' in __global__ function
                cuda_hello<<<1,1>>>(i+1);
                ^
helloWorld.cu:3:17: note: 'cuda_hello' declared here
__global__ void cuda_hello(int i){
```

Anyone knows if/how clang supports such recursion?

Comment: You can try `-fcuda-rdc` and see if that helps. Clang didn't have either relocatable code support or dynamic parallelism support. It now has the former (at least in very recent releases). Don't know about the latter

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for directing me to an interesting clang option that was unknown to me before! Tried it with clang++-11 but it didn't help.

Comment: OK so I guess the answer is probably no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing (July 2020), it would appear that while separate compilation support has been added to clang, dynamic parallelism ("nested kernels") is still not supported.